# Symfony Forms: Custom error message without changing the validation rule in validation.yml

Tags: php, validation, symfony

Is it possible to modify the default error message ("This value is not valid.") in validation.yml (or somewhere else) without changing the validation rule?

Reason: I have a <select> field, populated by id's from the database (through a Symfony entity). Therefore, the validation is already built-in. But I'd like to have a custom message.

P.S.: Here's a way to change the message globally, but I'd like to set it separately per field.
http://blog.geertvd.be/2011/09/01/custom-validation-messages-for-standard-validators-in-symfony2/

Comment: Do you really need a nice validation message for users who try to enter invalid data in a select field on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation on your Entity and set validation message for a field there. Something like this:

```
# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        gender:
            - Choice: { choices: [male, female], message: "Choose a valid gender." }
```

It also possible to do same with annotations, or any other Entity configuration. And translation is also available same way as with global error messages. See details in Symfony Book Validation chapter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Comment: But the choices (in your example [male, female]) are in the database. So I cannot list them in the yml file.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is just an example, in your case you can have only message option, you should give choices only if you'd like to limit input with the following two options. And one more thing, you will put this validation things on your Entity, and how this entity will be shown you will set in your FormType class. If you use annotations in your entity, then you can have something like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#constraint-configuration

Comment: And may be you should not use @Assert/Choice, may be in your case it's better to have @Assert/NotBlank? Depends on what are you checking, and set a message for that case. Even more, you can check for multiple things at once, and set message for every case.

Answer (score 0):

If im correct you can also just translate the "This value is not valid" message:

## validators.en.yml

author.name.not_blank: Please enter an author name.